# C++ Appending to an array

Tags: c++, append

```
const int fileLength = fileContent.length();
    char test[1000];
    for (int p = 0; p < fileLength; ++p){
        test[p].append(fileContent[p]); // Error: expression must have class type
    };
```

I'm attempting to append the characters of a text file into an array which i've created. Though I'm getting the error " expression must have class type ". Tried googling this error to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: If you want to use 'append', why do you use a char array instead of a string or vector?

Answer (score 5):

`test` is an array of char.  `test[p]` is a char.  `char` does not have any members.  In particular, it does not have an `append` member.

You probably want to make test a `std::vector<char>`

```
    const auto fileLength = fileContent.length();
    std::vector<char> test;
    for (const auto ch : fileContent)
    {
        test.push_back(ch);
    }
```

or even:

```
    std::vector<char> test( fileContent.begin(), fileContent.end() );
```

if you then really need to treat the `test` as an array (because you are interfacing to some C function for example), then use:

```
    char* test_pointer = &*test.begin();
```

If you want to use it as a nul-terminated string, then you should probably use std::string instead, and get the pointer with `test.c_str()`.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Was that addressed at me, or the OP?  I say "probably" in a couple of places, because there are occasions where that advice doesn't apply.

Comment: OP Deleted his comment, so did I just now.

Answer (score 0):

char array does not have any member function by the name append .However , std::string does have one member function named append like below :

```
string& append (const char* s, size_t n);
```

I think you by mistake have used char array instead of std::string .
std::string will resolve this problem like below :

```
const int fileLength = fileContent.length();
    string test;
    for (int p = 0; p < fileLength; ++p){
        test.append(fileContent[p],1); // Error: expression must have class type
    };
```

Better way would be **string test(fileContent)** .You can access test just like a array .Refer string class for more details .